# Error : When createRole command used in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Running following query on admin collection gives an error.

```
db.runCommand({
    createRole:"mynew",
    priviliges : [..],
    roles: [
    { role: "read", db: "admin" }
  ],
  writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }
})
```

**showing "error msg:no such cmd createRole"**

Comment: typo? crea**r**eRole

Comment: just a typo in error msg , command is right

Comment: What version of MongoDB server are you connecting to? User-defined roles (and the associated `createRole` command) require MongoDB 2.6.x or newer.

Comment: thank you i  am currently working in 2.4.9